# Proving Diophantine Equation has no solution using Legendre Symbol

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations, legendre-symbol

Given that $\left(\frac{10}{23}\right)=-1$. How would I go about showing that $9x^2-46(y^3+3y+1)=10$ has no integer solutions?

I believe it has something to do with Quadratic Reciprocity.

For example, we can show that $x^2-43y^2=73$ has no integer solutions by demonstrating that $x^2 \equiv 73(mod\:43)$ has no solutions as $$\left(\frac{73}{43}\right)=\left(\frac{30}{43}\right)=\left(\frac{2}{43}\right)\left(\frac{3}{43}\right)\left(\frac{5}{43}\right)=\left(\frac{43}{5}\right)=\left(\frac{3}{5}\right)=-1$$

I also believe that this shows that $x^2-43y^n=73, n \in Z$ has no integer solutions.

I imagine I am missing some jump between $9x^2-46(y^3+3y+1)=10$ and a Legendre Symbol that can be transformed into $\left(\frac{10}{23}\right)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Taking mod 23, we get that $ (3x)^2 \equiv 10 \pmod{23}$.

What does $\left( \frac{10}{23} \right) = - 1$ tell us about existence of solutions $x$?

Comment: It tells us that there is no solution x. Are you implying that because 23 is a factor of 46 and that $x^2 \equiv 10 (mod \: 23)$ has no solutions, that the original equation also has no solutions?

Comment: Yup! Exactly! $ $